# How to make selected tab active in bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code for creating the tabs

```
<ul ng-init="tab = 1" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <li class="active"><a ng-click="tab = 1">1. Shopping cart</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="tab = 2">2. Delivery Address</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="tab = 3">3. Place Order</a></li>
</ul>
```

First tab is active and looks like this.

[image]

But when i select 2nd, 3rd tab, its not getting active. How to make selected tab active and rest all inactive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul ng-init="tab = 1" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <li ng-class="{active:tab==1}"><a data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 1">1. Shopping cart</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:tab==2}"><a data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 2">2. Delivery Address</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:tab==3}"><a data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 3">3. Place Order</a></li>
</ul>
```